# Part of my code is not executing

Tags: c#

I wrote this code trying to list numbers below 50 from an array of 1000 numbers in which the numbers are generated randomly but line 25 seems not to be executed as i do not see its output on the console window!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace projecttest
{
    class linqs
    {
        public void generatenumbers(int number)
        {

            Random louda = new Random();
            int[] myarray = new int[number];
            for (int i = 0; i <number; i++)
            {
                myarray[i] = louda.Next(0,100);
            }

            var queryresult = from n in myarray
                              where n < 50
                              select n;

            Console.WriteLine("Numbers less than 50 are:");
            foreach (var ray in queryresult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ray);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            linqs ti = new linqs();
            ti.generatenumbers(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to scroll up console output? Or set breakpoint on that line?

Comment: When you copy in code samples like this, I'd recommend not putting in the line numbers. If someone wanted to copy/paste this into their editor, it would not be easy.

Comment: Your console buffer might be smaller than the amount of lines, that are printed, so it gets off screen. Try to increase it.

Comment: Unless your program blows up beforehand that line will be executed.

Comment: What *is* visible in the console window? (You can shorten consecutive lines of steadily increasing numbers if it is clear what was skipped.)

Comment: Can you post the console output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is executing but you are overflowing console output and you can't see all lines, try this code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Numbers less than 50 are:");
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",queryresult));
```

It will show values separated by `,` and you will see all values

Comment: Thanks its working now....didn't know about the overflowing issue but i got it now.....